# Not able to do first HTTP request in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, fetch, freshworks

I'm a super n00b trying to make an HTTP request to FreshSales in Google Cloud Function using node.js. 
Problems:

- not node proficient enough to do a proper google search
- don't have enough dev vocabulary to understand what I find online

However, here is the code I wrote (based on the GCF examples I found online):

```
/**
 * HTTP Cloud Function that makes an HTTP request
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.makeRequest = async (req, res) => {
    const url = 'https://mycompany.myfreshworks.com/crm/sales/api/contacts/123456'; // URL to send the request to
    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Token token=BLABLABLA"
        }
    };
    console.log(options);
    const response = await fetch(url, options);

    console.log(response.body)
    console.log("Response Status : " + response.status)

    res.sendStatus(response.ok ? response.body : response.status);
};
```

The answer I get is: **Function execution took 1033 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'** while I would much like to get a JSON response of some sort.
I don't really understand where my error is and if I faulted something in the setup or in the index.js function (above). 
Could somebody help me? 
Even a "video to watch" suggestion would help!
Thanks

Comment: Which example are you following? Also do you have that "token=" in your actual authorization header? Shouldn't be necessary after the first "Token "

Comment: The connection error means a timeout of the URL that you call. Did you try with a CURL?

Comment: @GabrielGarrett what would be the correct syntax? 
`"Token =BLABLABLA"` or `"Token BLABLABLA"`?



@guillaumeblaquiere Didn't try but will do today and update you!

Comment: Token BlabalaBla   no equal sign, just a space

Comment: Are you still facing any issues? @JuliAudroc

Comment: To be honest I got super frustrated and dropped the topic. BUT if you have a working script I would totally want to see it and test it out :pray: